# Advanced Custom Fields Repeater - How to reverse order (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the advanced custom fields repeater plugin to create a a big grid of images with links. I would like the newest items I create at the top, so what I'm asking is how do I reverse the the order via the code?

Any help would be great. Here is my current code

```
<?php if( have_rows('shop_product') ):        

            while ( have_rows('shop_product') ) : the_row(); 

        ?>

                <div class="shop-item">
                    <div class="image-hover">
                        <div class="image-hover-inner">

                            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('product_image');?>">

                            <div class="image-caption">
                            <div class="image-caption-inner">
                            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('product_url');?>" target="_blank"><?php the_sub_field('product_brand');?><br>
                            Buy Now</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; 
        else :
        endif;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

off the top of my head, using output buffer - not the cleanest way though

```
<?php $outs = array(); if( have_rows('shop_product') ):        

            while ( have_rows('shop_product') ) : the_row();  ob_start();

        ?>

                <div class="shop-item">
                    <div class="image-hover">
                        <div class="image-hover-inner">

                            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('product_image');?>">

                            <div class="image-caption">
                            <div class="image-caption-inner">
                            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('product_url');?>" target="_blank"><?php the_sub_field('product_brand');?><br>
                            Buy Now</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php $outs[] = ob_get_clean(); endwhile; 
        else :
        endif;
        $outs = array_reverse($outs);
        echo implode($outs);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `get_field('my_repeater')` to get the repeater fields as an array which you can loop over.

Then using PHP's `array_reverse()` function, you get a reversed array you can loop over.

The only difference is you have to access the fields as array keys rather than using ACF's `sub_field` functions.

For your example:

```
<?php $products = array_reverse(get_field('shop_product'));

foreach ($products as $product): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $product['product_image']; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $product['product_url']; ?>">Buy now</a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This is an old question now but for those returning in the far future, I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

It may not answer the actual question, but may solve the problem. 
If you are displaying rows of repeater, you could use CSS display:flex together with flex-flow:row/column-reverse;

As it may only be necessary to swap order to DISPLAY it

Example:

```
display:flex;
flex-flow:row-reverse;
```

Comment: While this would work from a display/visual-only perspective, it's not great in terms of user journey, screen-readers, etc. so I'd advise against it. Far better practice to structure your DOM in the order you want to display things in the first place.